# Different between two cases here

Tags: java, if-statement

I am just thinking, is there any performance wise benefit between following scenarios.

Case 1

```
int x = 2;
boolean y = false;

if (x == 2) {
  y = true;
}
```

Case 2

```
int x = 2;
boolean y = (x == 2);
```

My idea is, case 1 is more readable.

Comment: You can easily test it with timestamps

Comment: The JIT compiler will probably optimize this away as `x` is fixed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just want to know is there any difference in these two. I am not expecting any performance gain here.

Comment: Take a look at the bytecode. There are very small differences.

Answer (score 6):

There will be a tiny, tiny difference in performance (the first version adds an additional `if` instruction after all, but even that might get optimized away by the static compiler or the JIT compiler), but anyway it'll be negligible. For such a simple case, it's better to optimize for readability, forget about micro optimizations.

Answer (score 4):

in both cases you are

- comparing `x` to a literal `2`
- setting `y` to a value

but only in the first case do you have a branch.  In the second case, you merely set `y` to the result of the comparison.

Case 2 does less operations because of this.

But the compiler probably optimizes it that way for you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Peter started, but didn't finish. For reference (Java 7 compiler), this

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 2;
        boolean y = (x == 2);
    }
}
```

compiles to

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_2           // load the int value 2 onto the stack
       1: istore_1           // store int value into variable 1
       2: iload_1            // load an int value from local variable 1
       3: iconst_2           // load the int value 2 onto the stack
       4: if_icmpne     11   // if ints are not equal, branch to instruction at branchoffset 
       7: iconst_1           // load the int value 1 onto the stack (true)
       8: goto          12
      11: iconst_0           // load the int value 0 onto the stack (false)
      12: istore_2           // store int value into variable 2
      13: return
```

while

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 2;
        boolean y = false;

        if (x == 2) {
          y = true;
        }
    }

}
```

compiles to

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_2          // load the int value 2 onto the stack
       1: istore_1          // store int value into variable 1
       2: iconst_0          // load the int value 0 onto the stack (false)
       3: istore_2          // store int value into variable 2
       4: iload_1           // load an int value from local variable 1
       5: iconst_2          // load the int value 2 onto the stack
       6: if_icmpne     11  // if ints are not equal, branch to instruction at branchoffset
       9: iconst_1          // load the int value 1 onto the stack
      10: istore_2          // store int value into variable 2
      11: return
```

Both have a branching statement.

To answer the question, you really won't gain anything.